# Python prints arrays twice

Tags: python, printing

I have written the following implementation of the Extended Euclidean Algorithm:

```
def extended_euclid(a, b):
    x_k = 1       # read x_k
    x_k1 = 0      # read x_(k+1)
    y_k = 0       # read y_k
    y_k1 = 1      # read y_(k+1)
    sign = 1
    while b != 0:
        q = a//b
        r = a - q*b
        a = b
        b = r
        xx = x_k1
        yy = y_k1
        x_k1 = q*x_k1 + x_k
        y_k1 = q*y_k1 + y_k
        x_k = xx
        y_k = yy
        sign = -sign
    x = sign*x_k
    y = sign*y_k
    return [a, x, y]
```

It works as exptected but when I try to print out the result of a function call using the standard function "print" the output gets printed twice. So when I do

`print(extended_euclid(15,10))`

I get the output

```
[5, 1, 1]
[5, 1, 1]
```

I do not understand why the output gets printed twice, could you explain that to me. 
Also when  I do

```
a = extended_euclid(15,10)
print(a[1])
```

I get

```
1
1
```

which I do not understand either.

EDIT: The problem was that I mistakenly imported a file twice, which led to some unexpected results. Maybe this helps somebody.

Comment: I doubt this is all your code, please take a look at your script and make sure you aren't printing this 2x or somehow running this 2x.

Comment: I copied your code and its working with printing only one time!

Comment: If this is all your code - Are you sure your shell is properly configured? Running this code in Python 3.6.6 prints the resulting list once.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the rest of your code, if you print this euclid function somewhere, delete that print and just call function instead. On my machine this code prints only one result.